# Does "格秀拉康" have an equivalent proper noun in English?

Tags: translation

格秀拉康 is most likely a Chinese transliteration of Tibetan.

The English is more likely to reflect the Tibetan pronunciation rather than the Chinese one, e.g.: 甘孜 in English becomes something like: *Garzê*.

I wouldn't even know how to began to hazard a guess.

Information online is scant.

Ideas?

---

edit: perhaps 拉康 is something like Lhakhang?

edit 2: is it kartsog lhakhang?

Comment: Try to coin a word in English which sounds like that, as the famous Chinese writer Lin Yutang named one of the characters in his novel "Moment in Peking" Mr. New, which is 牛先生, but not 新先生.

Comment: @NanningYouth It would be best made from the original Tibetan, which I know little to nothing about.

Comment: ＠user3306356 do you have the context in which this word/phrase in found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is [Kartsog Lhakhang](http://www.trace.org/field/dancing-mud).
It means the "Temple of the white [pure] assembly".

> Kartsog Lhakhang (格秀拉康) is the oldest and most important Buddhist temple in Yushu (玉树) town. Its exact origins are unknown, but a small temple on this site dates back to the founding of Jyekundo (Yushu) town by Sakya Pandita (萨迦·班智达, 1182-1251) in the thirteenth century. The present temple took its shape in the eighteenth century. Located in the heart of the historic town, it is the local community's neighborhood temple, the most important place in their daily life. It is also used for fasting practice (Tibetan: nyungney 斋戒), hence the name Kartsog Lhakhang, “**temple of the white [pure] assembly**.”

康 (khang) means the house or building. For example,
医院 (hospital) 门康
商店 (store or shop) 村康
旅馆 (hotel or inn) 准康
书店 (bookstore) 贝村康
银行 (bank) 威康

拉 (lha) means the heaven or god.

Then, 拉康 (lhakhang) means the temple (神殿, 庙, 寺).

The Chinese name of Kartsog Lakhang (格秀拉康) is [格秀经堂](http://www.chengduo.gov.cn/html/489/154988.html) or [嘎措寺](https://www.douban.com/group/topic/33655789/).

Comment: Does all Tibetan match up with Chinese characters?

Comment: For example: It's a wild guess but does ཁང་ always equate to 康? I don't know anything about Tibetan.

Comment: Both "Kartsog Lakhang" and "格秀拉康" are transliterations.
I do not know any Tibetan characters either, not to mention the pronunciation.
So, I have no idea about whether they match up or not.